# Can´t use add-on in Android Studio: "platform not found"

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, add-on

In our project we are using an add-on instead of the standard Android SDK.

There is a new version of the add-on, it is in the add-ons folder, listed among the SDKs to compile with, but when we select it, we get an error from gradle saying:

```
Error: Module 'app' platform 'add-on_name' not found.
Open Android SDK Manager and install all missing platforms.
```

Our current setup is:

```
Android Studio 3.0 canary 5
gradle wrapper distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
```

I have submitted the issue with the add-on developer, but it seems more like an Android tools/Gradle bug, so I am trying my chances here. It used to work without issues before Gradle 2.0/Android Studio 2.3